# How do I implement a WkWebView in a cross-platform mobile app project (VS 2017/Xamarin)?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a cross-platform mobile app (Android/iOS) which implements the generic WebView control.  This works well for most circumstances, but some iOS users complain that, when attempting to load a certain resource-intensive web page, the app "goes black" and then focus returns to the main menu view.  My suspicion is that the app is choking due to the amount of content and processing overhead of the web page, but frankly this is a blind guess and I don't have the resources (such as an iPhone at my disposal) in order to verify this.  Using an iPhone simulator on a Mac does not reproduce the "black screen" issue.

Therefore, I am attempting to implement in parallel WkWebView for iOS devices at version 8.0 and above as this is presumably more performant and *might* alleviate the problem.  It is just about working, but there seems to be a disconnect between the ViewController and ContentPage which is supposed to host the WkWebView control which I have been unable to rectify.

Below is the general implementation:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class WkWebViewPage : ContentPage
{
    public WkWebViewPage (string url, string title)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Title = title;

        App.GetWkWebView(this, url);
    }
}
```

The markup for WkWebPageView has no inner content.

The method App.GetWkWebView is a delegate of type Action implemented as a static property in the main App class.  This is assigned in the FinishedLaunching method of the AppDelegate class (iOS project) to a static method in the static class I am using to manage invoking the WkWebView.  This class is implemented as such:

```
public static class WkWebViewController
{
    private static WKWebView _wkWebView;

    public static void GetWkWebView(Page parentView, string url)
    {
        if(_wkWebView == null)
        {

    // INSERT ATTEMPTED APPROACHES BELOW HERE

            var frame = view.Frame;

            var cgRect = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(frame.X, frame.Y, frame.Width, frame.Height);

            _wkWebView = new WKWebView(cgRect, new WKWebViewConfiguration());

            view.AddSubview(_wkWebView);

    // NavigationDelegate is a custom class; not germane to the issue
            _wkWebView.NavigationDelegate = new NavigationDelegate();
        }

        var nsUrl = new NSUrl(url);
        var request = new NSUrlRequest(nsUrl);

        _wkWebView.LoadRequest(request);
    }
}
```

Here is where the trouble begins.  I have tried two approaches to obtaining the appropriate ViewController -- and more pertinently, the UIView object:

1)

```
var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(parentView);

if (renderer == null)
{
    renderer = Platform.CreateRenderer(parentView);
    Platform.SetRenderer(parentView, renderer);
}

var view = renderer.ViewController.View;
```

This results in the following:

[image: App Screenshot 1]
<sub>(source: [aquaspy.com](https://uat2.agspy.aquaspy.com/misc/app_1.png))</sub>

The content area is white/blank.  The http request is submitted successfully as a 200 response is received.  Note that the navigation bar above the content area properly displays.

2)

```
var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;

var vc = window.RootViewController;

while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
{
    vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
}

var view = vc.View;
```

Which results in:

[image: App Screenshot 2]
<sub>(source: [aquaspy.com](https://uat2.agspy.aquaspy.com/misc/app_2.png))</sub>

In this case, the web page displays; however, the WkWebView control takes up the entire screen, obscuring the navigation bar (and seemingly the Status Bar).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!